# Drag element on Playwright

Tags: go, playwright

I would like to know if it is possible click and drag an element of web page with Golang Playwright, because it exists click and move, but not both joints.

Comment: your queston lacks code and supplementary information. Probably most people dont even know the library you mention. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

I got a working version that drags an element in Playwright. This is the implementation in TypeScript.

```
async dragElement(element: ElementHandle, xOffset: number, yOffset: number, page: Page): Promise<void> {
  const elementBox = await element.boundingBox();
  if (!elementBox) {
    throw new Error('Unable to find bounding box on element');
  }

  const elementCenterX = elementBox.x + elementBox.width / 2;
  const elementCenterY = elementBox.y + elementBox.height / 2;

  await element.hover();
  await page.mouse.down();
  await page.mouse.move(elementCenterX + xOffset, elementCenterY + yOffset);
  await page.mouse.up();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me. But I used with "Locator" instead of "ElementHandle"